# identifier "taskRtpLock" is undefined

Tags: vxworks

I have included `taskLib.h` and I am calling `taskRtpLock()`
Default Build Spec: `SIMLINUXdiab`
Active Build Spec: `SIMLINUXdiab`

`Error: identifier "taskRtpLock" is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

There is two files called `taskLib.h`: one is located in `$(TGT_DIR)/h/` and another is in `$(TGT_DIR)/usr/h`. The first is for kernel task and the second one is for Real Time Processes. Guess for some reason the first one is included in your case.

But I'm not quite sure about the actual reason because right now I have no sources to check it out. Anyway, ensure you added RTP components to your project with the following commands:

```
$ cd /path/to/WindRiver/
$ wrenv -p vxworks-6.5
$ cd path/to/your/project
$ vxprj bundle add projectFile.wpj BUNDLE_RTP_DEVELOP
```